# Predicting the Entropy of the entire Password Database

Tags: passwords

Suppose that the passwords created under some specific composition rule "C" is to be tested for the security. One of the way could be to conduct survey on x number of people and measure the average entropy of the passwords created by them. 
What should be the least value of x so that approximate entropy of the password database created by 6 billion users under the same composition rule "C" can be predicted?

I want to evaluate which composition rules create more secure passwords, assuming that I can collect the survey based password data.

Comment: This appears to really be a statistics question focused on determining the appropriate sample size.

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression this is an invalid line of questioning the problem.

Rule C * number of people does not define the entropy, the algorithm used for encrypting the password does. Unless the passwords are kept in clear text the password database as such will only show entropy against the algorithm.

Comment: I want to evaluate which composition rules create more secure passwords, assuming that I can collect the survey based password data.

Comment: Now i understand better. Unless these passwords are to be used on automated systems the human limitations will always play an important role.

There are quite a bit of sources on non-human friendly password generating rules. In the end, if it is too complex or too long to remember passwords are written down for reference.

There have been experiments with ultra-long passwords because people have an easier time remembering them as passwords. would be less because of less complexity ( just letters and punctuation ) Demanding a multiple digit cipher could prove interesting though.

Comment: This might be of interest to you [https://pthree.org/2011/03/07/strong-passwords-need-entropy/]